# Arrays size as variable - what is correct now?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

Im using gcc to compile my programs:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I know that there are different C standards:

1. K&R C standard (classic C)
2. ANSI C
3. ISO 90
4. ... where ANSI C and ISO C are almost the same, also known as C90 or C89
5. ANSI C99 and ISO/IEC 9899 known as C99
6. C11 (current C standard)

My point is, they have differences when its about declaring a static array.

In C89 (C90) you cant have an array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 4; //or const int n = 4
    int tab1[n] = {1,2,3,4};

    return 0;
}
```

but in C99, you can:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 4; // or const int n = 4
    int tab1[n] = {1,2,3,4};

    int tab2[3] = {5,6,7};

    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile this version with `gcc arrays_size.c -std=c99 -o arrays_size`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 4; // or const int n = 4
    int tab1[n] = {1,2,3,4};
    return 0;
}
```

it gives me:

```
arrays_size.c: In function ‘main’:
arrays_size.c:6:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
arrays_size.c:6:5: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
arrays_size.c:6:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘tab1’) [enabled by default]
arrays_size.c:6:5: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
arrays_size.c:6:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘tab1’) [enabled by default]
arrays_size.c:6:5: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
arrays_size.c:6:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘tab1’) [enabled by default]
arrays_size.c:6:5: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
arrays_size.c:6:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘tab1’) [enabled by default]
```

although *should be* correct, right? Same as for compiling with `gcc arrays_size.c -o arrays_size` ...

My questions:

1. What is a right way to do it?
2. How about the newest C11, does it allow to declare an array with a variable as its size?
3. And how about other standards?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried to *read* the error messsges?

Comment: AFAIK ANSI C and ISO C89 are the same standard. Also, K & R C is not actually a standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't initialize an array that way when the array's size is a variable. This will not work.

```
int tab1[n] = {1,2,3,4};
```

But this will:

```
int tab1[4] = {1,2,3,4};
```

`gcc` accepts your character array with a size of `n` is not C89-compliant. `gcc` supports it as an extension.

Comment: You sure? Is it the same for EVERY C standard?

Comment: C89 does not allow the use of variables as array dimensions, but C99 does.

Comment: Huh, so why when I compile with `-std=c99` flag I get the same warnings as when I compile without this flag?

Comment: Because `n` is not a compile time constant - however - `gcc` supports vla as an extension (even in C89 mode).

Comment: Ok, so now I know that in C89 I cant have `int n = 3; int tab[n];` but can have it in C99. How about other standards, do you know?

Comment: @mazix - C11 supports vlas as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is there actually a reason to have *n* be an integer? If you used a preprocessor macro (#define), it would work in both situations.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 4
int tab1[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1,2,3,4};
```

A safer implementation:

```
int tab1[] = {1,2,3,4}
int n = sizeof(tab1)/sizeof(tab1[0]);
```

This moves the size computation in a way that would allow you to modify the array without also modifying the the size declarator.